# Where should I put my drawing code

Tags: c++, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should actors in a game be responsible for drawing themselves?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/should-actors-in-a-game-be-responsible-for-drawing-themselves)

How can I refractor the following, to move my drawing functions from the h-file into a GraphicsManager class?

I have the following scenario:

```
//drawingFunctions.h
void drawTexturedQuad( Texture texture, Vector2 pos, Vector2 dim) {
    // bind texture...
    glBegin(...);    // draw  
    //...
    glEnd(...);
}

#include "drawingFunctions.h"
class Player { 
    void drawPlayer(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
class Enemy { 
    void drawEnemy(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
class Item { 
    void drawItem(){ drawTexturedQuad( texture, pos, dim) } 
};
// and so on for the other  components, you get the idea...
```

I figured I could make all these classes extend another class, say drawableGameComponent. Would that be a good idea? What are other suggestions?

Comment: You should see [this question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14133/should-actors-in-a-game-be-responsible-for-drawing-themselves) which is essentially asking the same thing (do objects draw themselves or does something else draw them?).

Comment: While this is an interesting read, I don't really see how it solves my (implementation) problem? I think I am doing what is suggested there, in the sense that I am trying to have my renderer draw the components by using my `drawTexturedQuad` function (instead of having the render code in the components themselves). I edited my question to make that clearer.

Comment: The idea is that your Player class, for example *has* a class that represents a textured quad, and then you have some kind of rendering class that collects all these objects in all of your entity types and draws them.  Unless you're asking how to put `drawTexturedQuad` inside of a class?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. So if by "has" you mean "has as a data member", wouldn't it then be a good idea to make all my entity types extend a textured quad class instead of adding the textured quad as a separate data member to every entity? For my understanding, it would help a lot if you could formulate your idea into an answer with a short code example.

Comment: Also, wouldn't your solution mean updating both the actual player object and its corresponding textured quad object every frame? That would mean doubling my updates... so that can't be a recommended approach!?